# ANTLR doesn't match correct parser rule

Tags: java, parsing, antlr

I am trying to create a parser for the DOCTOR script of the old ELIZA chatbot program.

The DOCTOR script, simplified here to a simple Welcome line followed by a line defining how "The Doctor" responds to a User input of say "IF ONLY I WAS THINNER" :

```
(I AM THE DOCTOR.)
(IF 3 ((0 IF 0)(DO YOU 3)(YOU WISH THAT 3)))
```

Here is the Lexer:

```
ALL_CHARS: [0-9A-Z, .];
KEY_CHARS: [A-Z];
LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';
NUM: [0-9];
SPACE: ' ';
WS: ('\n')+ -> skip;
```

and the Parser:

```
main: item* EOF;
item: (rWelcome | rKeyDecompReAssy );


rKeyDecompReAssy: LPAREN rKeyPri rDecompReAssy RPAREN;
rKeyPri: rKey SPACE rPri;
rKey: KEY_CHARS+;
rPri: NUM+;

rDecompReAssy: LPAREN rDecomp rReAssyList RPAREN;
rDecomp: LPAREN ALL_CHARS+ RPAREN;

rReAssyList: (rReAssy)+;
rReAssy: LPAREN reAssy RPAREN;
reAssy: ALL_CHARS+;

rWelcome: LPAREN reAssy RPAREN;
```

which defines a rule for the **Welcome** line (**rWelcome**) and one for the **IF** line (**rDecompReAssy**), which attempts to match 4 components:  Key, Pri, Decomp and ReAssyList.

I use the ANTLR Preview of Android Studio.

The problem is that both lines are matched to rWelcome.

The Welcome line is OK of course, but the error message for the second is:

```
line 2:6 missing ')' at '('
line 2:45 mismatched input ')' expecting {<EOF>, '('}
```

How do I make the two rules unambiguous?

Comment: Your parser is doing way too much, and the lexer is doing way too little. Every character in the input is lexed as `ALL_CHARS`. I don't know enough about "DOCTOR script" to know the right way to lex/parse it though.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, your lexer never creates `KEY_CHARS`-, `SPACE`- and `NUM`-tokens. This is because the `ALL_CHARS` token also matches the chars defined in those tokens. And when 2 or more lexer rules match the same characters, the one defined first "wins". No matter if a parser rule is trying to match a `KEY_CHARS` token, the lexer simply creates a `ALL_CHARS` token: the lexer works independently from the parser.

What you could do is something like this:

```
main             : item* EOF;
item             : (rWelcome | rKeyDecompReAssy );
rKeyDecompReAssy : LPAREN rKeyPri rDecompReAssy RPAREN;
rKeyPri          : rKey SPACE rPri SPACE; // Note: I added the last `SPACE`
rKey             : KEY_CHARS+;
rPri             : NUM+;
rDecompReAssy    : LPAREN rDecomp rReAssyList RPAREN;
rDecomp          : LPAREN all_chars+ RPAREN;
rReAssyList      : (rReAssy)+;
rReAssy          : LPAREN reAssy RPAREN;
reAssy           : all_chars+;
rWelcome         : LPAREN reAssy RPAREN;
all_chars        : NUM | KEY_CHARS | SPACE | OTHER_CHAR;

KEY_CHARS  : [A-Z];
LPAREN     : '(';
RPAREN     : ')';
NUM        : [0-9];
SPACE      : ' ';
WS         : ('\n')+ -> skip;
OTHER_CHAR : [.,];
```

Comment: Brilliant Bart! I think though that ALL_CHARS always "won" whatever the order in the grammar file. I think it's because it was the longest. So your solution of only having one Lexer rule for a text string is great. Thank you for getting me out of this horrible mess.

Comment: The ALL_CHARS was always 1 char long. And you’re welcome, of course.